# Word 2013: pages are missing in docx file (was edited with Word 2003)

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2013, microsoft-word-2003, docx

I had a doc file, which was converted to a docx file with Word 2013. Everything is working here. Then I made changes on this file with Word 2003 and saved the docx.

Now on a Word 2013 only the half of the document is shown. The rest of the document isn't shown. On Word 2003 everything is working as intended. Tracking changes is active in this document.

So it seems that the compatibility addon for Word 2003 (doxc compatibility addon) has introduced some errors in this document.

What can I do?

**Edit:**

The open and repair feature of Word 2013/2003 didn't worked.

**Edit 2:**

Seems that some Word versions can handle the file without problems and some not.

Works:

- Microsoft Office Word 2003 (11.8350.8341) SP3
- Microsoft Offiche Home and Business 2010 - Microsoft Word 2010 (14.0.7149.5000) 32-Bit
- Office 365 ProPlus (15.0.4711.1003)

Doesn't work:

- Microsoft Office Home and Business 2013 (15.0.4711.1003) => Microsoft Word 2013 (15.0.4711.1001) MSO (15.0.4711.1003) 32-Bit
- Microsoft Office Home and Business 2013 (15.0.4719.1002) => Microsoft Word 2013 (15.0.4719.1000) MSO (15.0.4719.1000) 32-Bit

I also tried some repair tools and you can forget them.

**Edit 3:**

Pages 5.5.3 can open the file. The dropbox viewer also hasn't some problems. LibreOffice 4.3.0.4 has some general problems because it displays many things wrong. Word Online can display the document correctly (reading mode), but can't edit it.

Comment: You made changes to which version of the document?  Have you verified you perhaps didn't open the other file instead?  If something did happen there isn't much you can do at this point the work was lost.

Comment: The doc is a very old one. I only work on the docx on which I made the changes. I think you are right. Do you know a good docx repair tool? Or how can I get the text of my Word 2003 into Word 2013 without errors?

Comment: I don't do software recomendation tools for "repair tools" i am to suspicious of those types of requests.

Comment: Going back and forth between versions can cause confusion. In some cases even cause file corruption because of the constant conversions. Is there a way to only use one version of Word?

Comment: @CharlieRB: In future perhaps. The management has to approve that new licenses are bought ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have such a problem you should look on the place where the document is cut off. In my case that was the following page after the last page which was displayed in Word 2013. Here there was a comment on an image. Removing and inserting the content of the comment again seems to work.

Now the file is fully shown in Word 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I see you mentioned a dropbox viewer. Did you know dropbox and most other cloud storage services have version history? If this file was being transferred between computers via dropbox during this, or if it resided in there before corruption, then you can use revision history to backtrack the file safely. This dropbox page helps explain the process : https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/11

Comment: Thanks for your addition. No, I didn't know that. I uploaded the file to dropbox afterwards so there is "no revision". But I have an older revision for myself. Because there is much work in this document I don't want to make everything new (and perhaps introducing the error again). Ideally the Word document can be repaired, but it seemst that only some Word versions have problems with it (especially Word 2013).

Answer (score -1):

Office 365 missing text from Office 2007 document.
in print layout only 1 page showed.
In read mode all pages showed.
Nothing in any forum worked.
Finally I went to Outlining and showed all levels.
Complete document was there.
I copied all text and pasted into a NEW Office 365 word document.
All text was there.  Saved and re-opened - ALL THERE

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. Op is using neither of the word versions in your answer.